# How do I avoid hot partitions when using DyanmoDB row level access control?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database-partitioning

I’m looking at adding row-level permissions to a DynamoDB table using `dynamodb:LeadingKeys` to restrict access per Provider ID. Currently I only have one provider ID, but I know I will have more. However they providers will vary in size with those sizes being very unbalanced.

If I use Provider ID as my partition key, it seems to me like my DB will end up with very hot partitions for the large providers and mostly unused ones for the smaller providers. Prior to adding the row-level access control I was using  deviceId as the partition key since it is a more random name, so partitions well, but now I think I have to move that to the sort key.

Current partitioning that works well:

```
HASHKEY: DeviceId
```

With permissions I think I need to go to:

```
HASHKEY: ProviderID (only a handful of them)
RangeKey: DeviceId
```

Any suggestions as to a better way to set this up?

Comment: What about hash key = `${ProviderId}.${DeviceId}`?  ...assuming you always know the provider when querying a device.  (Otherwise your other proposed scheme wouldn't work, either.)

Comment: Most of my use cases for quivering are for all the devices belonging to one provider. So I’m not sure I can use the permissioning that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you no longer need to worry about hot partitions in DynamoDB, especially if the partition keys which are being requested the most remain relatively constant.

More Info: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/

Comment: True but still best to avoid blatant imbalances.  Worse, one partition key per "provider" would restrict the total possible data for any single provider to 10GB max for data and indexes, *if* LSIs are used:   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.ItemCollections.SizeLimit

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Michael's comment...

If you don't need a range key now...why add one?

The only reason to have a range key is that you need to `Query` DDB and return multiple records.

If all you ever need is a single record using `GetItem`, then you don't need a range key.

Simply concatenate `${ProviderId}.${DeviceId}` together to make up your hash key.

**Edit**
Since you want to be able to list device Ids for a single provider, then you do need providerID as the partition key and deviceID as the range key.

As Icehorn's answer mentions, "hot partitions" aren't as big a deal as they used to be.  Unless you expect the data for a single providerID to go over 10GB, I'd start with the simple implementation of hashKey(providerID).

If you have expect more than 10GB of data or you end up with a hot partition...then consider concatenating (1..n) integer to the providerID.

This will mean that you'd have to query multiple partitions to get all the deviceIDs.

This approach is detailed in [Multi Tenant SaaS Storage Strategies](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Multi_Tenant_SaaS_Storage_Strategies.pdf)

Comment: So with the `LeadingKeys` style permissioning, can I do a starts-with? There are times when I want to retrieve all of the device IDs belonging to a certain provider.

Comment: In that case, you'd need the device-id as the range key and provider as the hash key.  When using `query()` the hash key test is always =

Comment: Right, so back to my original problem. Hot partitions for the major provider. :(

Comment: nah, you can PK on the {providerId}_{deviceId} without Sort Key (SK). If you wanted to have Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) or another way to find a given result, you could add an SK with date or another compound value there but you would avoid hot partitioning like you asked and not need SK.